# X is already defined as object X during compiling Scala Android multiproject with Android SDK Plugin

Tags: android, scala, sbt, android-sdk-plugin

Recently I've started experimenting with Scala and Android. Initially I used `jp.leafytree.android-scala` plugin but over the time I've got more and more problems with it that I hoped I could solve simply by moving project to SBT with Android SDK Plugin.

At the moment I am struggling with the following error:

```
[error] /media/Workspaces/Project/modules/core/target/android/generated/source/com/example/client/core/BuildConfig.java:6: BuildConfig is already defined as object BuildConfig
[error] public final class BuildConfig {
[error]                    ^
[error] /media/Workspaces/Project/modules/core/target/android/generated/source/com/example/client/core/R.java:10: R is already defined as object R
[error] public final class R {
[error]                    ^
[error] /media/Workspaces/Project/modules/core/target/android/generated/source/com/example/client/core/TR.scala:6: TypedResource is already defined as case class TypedResource
[error] case class TypedResource[A](id: Int)
[error]            ^
[error] /media/Workspaces/Project/modules/core/target/android/generated/source/com/example/client/core/TR.scala:7: TypedLayout is already defined as case class TypedLayout
[error] case class TypedLayout[A](id: Int)
[error]            ^
[error] /media/Workspaces/Project/modules/core/target/android/generated/source/com/example/client/core/TR.scala:9: TR is already defined as object TR
[error] object TR {
[error]        ^
[error] /media/Workspaces/Project/modules/core/target/android/generated/source/com/example/client/core/TR.scala:119: TypedFindView is already defined as trait TypedFindView
[error] trait TypedFindView extends Any {
[error]       ^
[error] /media/Workspaces/Project/modules/core/target/android/generated/source/com/example/client/core/TR.scala:124: TypedResource is already defined as object TypedResource
[error] object TypedResource {
[error]        ^
[error] 7 errors found
```

I am not sure which SBT setting causes this error. My config is:

```
/
+-- modules/
| +-- core/ (library)
| +-- domain/ (library)
| +-- app/ (application)
|
+-- project/
  +-- Build.scala
  +-- Dependencies.scala
  +-- Settings.scala
  +-- plugins.sbt
```

`project/plugins.sbt`:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.hanhuy.sbt" % "android-sdk-plugin" % "1.5.12")
```

`project/Build.scala`:

```
import sbt._

object Build extends android.AutoBuild {

  import Dependencies._
  import Settings._

  lazy val core = project.from("core")
    .configureAsLibrary
    .configureModule

  lazy val domain = project.from("domain")
    .configureAsLibrary
    .configureModule
    .dependsOnLibraries(core)

  lazy val app = project.from("app")
    .configureModule
    .dependsOnLibraries(domain)
}
```

`project/Dependencies.scala`:

```
import sbt._

trait Dependencies {

  val scalaVersionUsed = "2.11.7"

  // resolvers
  val commonResolvers = Seq(
    Resolver sonatypeRepo "public",
    Resolver typesafeRepo "releases"
  )

  // ... libraries ...

  val mainDeps = Seq(appcompat, design, support, multidex, scalaLib, sqlDroid, slick, shapeless, joda, jodaConvert,
    facebook)

  val testDeps = Seq(mockito, spec2, spec2Core, spec2JUnit)
}

object Dependencies extends Dependencies {

  implicit class ProjectFrom(project: Project) {

    private val commonDir = "modules"

    def from(dir: String): Project = project in file(s"$commonDir/$dir")
  }

  implicit class DependsOnLibraries(project: Project) {

    import android.Dependencies.RichProject

    def dependsOnLibraries(projects: ProjectReference*): Project = project.androidBuildWith(projects:_*)
  }
}
```

`project/Settings.scala`:

```
import android.Plugin._
import sbt._
import sbt.Keys._

trait Settings {

  import Dependencies._

  private val modulesSettings = Seq(
    organization := "com.example",
    version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT",

    scalaVersion := scalaVersionUsed,

    resolvers ++= commonResolvers,

    libraryDependencies ++= mainDeps,
    libraryDependencies ++= testDeps map (_ % "test")
  )
}

object Settings extends Settings {

  implicit class LibraryConfigurator(project: Project) {

    def configureAsLibrary: Project = project.settings(androidBuildAar:_*)
  }

  implicit class ModuleConfigurator(project: Project) {

    def configureModule: Project = project.settings(modulesSettings: _*)
  }
}
```

It basically just applies `project.settings(androidBuildAar:_*)` to `core` and `domain, then adds library dependencies and some options.

`sbt clean` didn't help. Manual removal of all `target/` directories with their contents didn't helped either: with next sbt compile all files will be generated again and so does the error. What is its cause and what can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`androidBuild`* and `AutoBuild` cannot be used together.

In your case, remove AutoBuild

https://github.com/pfn/android-sdk-plugin/issues/88

Comment: Thanks! That solved problem with first library (`core`). Now I have another with the `domain` project (X is already defined as object X). I understand that it's cause is slightly different and I should post another question?

Comment: In the same vein, you cannot use `androidBuild` together with `androidBuildAar`

Comment: Also, that style of build configuration is just about entirely unreadable.

Comment: Well, it has its advantages when I have a lot more configurations than in this example and want avoid code duplication.

Comment: Android projects rarely get complicated enough to warrant this. Code reuse can be achieved without all of the indirection.